# How to anchor Elements to BottomSheet with JetpackCompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using BottomSheetScaffold to display a BottomSheet.

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
    bottomSheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    )
)

BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetContent = {
        MySheet()
    },
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState) {
        MyMainContent()
    }
)
```

Now I would like to display elements above the sheet which will move along when expanding or closing the sheet. e.g. like this:

[image]

The elements are not FloatingActionButtons.

Is there a Modifier I could use? Can this be achieved with the Box Layout, is there some CoordinatorLayout mode for it? Do I need to write my own layout?

In general: How can I achieve this with Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's something built-in in compose (in version `rc01`).
But you can achieve this behavior setting transparent color to the `sheetBackgroundColor` parameter... Something like this:

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
    bottomSheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    )
)

BottomSheetScaffold(
    // the whole sheet will be transparent.
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent, 
    sheetContent = {
        Column {
            Text(
                text = "Element",
                Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .padding(24.dp)
            )
            // Your bottom sheet content
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)) {
                // content
            }
        }
    },
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState
) {
    // The main content
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black)) {
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is there any new way to implement this now that it is 2023? I couldn't find anything myself

Comment: Using M3 library, I believe you can pass a custom `sheetDragHandle`.